# MySQL Improving speed of order by statements

Tags: mysql

I've got a table in a MySQL db with about 25000 records.  Each record has about 200 fields, many of which are TEXT.  There's nothing I can do about the structure - this is a migration from an old flat-file db which has 16 years of records, and many fields are "note" type free-text entries.

Users can be viewing any number of fields, and order by any single field, and any number of qualifiers.  There's a big slowdown in the sort, which is generally taking several seconds, sometimes as much as 7-10 seconds.

an example statement might look like this:

```
select a, b, c from table where b=1 and c=2 or a=0 order by a desc limit 25
```

There's never a star-select, and there's always a limit, so I don't think the statement itself can really be optimized much.

I'm aware that indexes can help speed this up, but since there's no way of knowing what fields are going to be sorted on, i'd have to index all 200 columns - what I've read about this doesn't seem to be consistent.  I understand there'd be a slowdown when inserting or updating records, but assuming that's acceptable, is it advisable to add an index to each column?

I've read about sort_buffer_size but it seems like everything I read conflicts with the last thing I read - is it advisable to increase this value, or any of the other similar values (read_buffer_size, etc)?

Also, the primary identifier is a crazy pattern they came up with in the nineties.  This is the PK and so should be indexed by virtue of being the PK (right?).  The records are (and have been) submitted to the state, and to their clients, and I can't change the format.  This column needs to sort based on the logic that's in place, which involves a stored procedure with string concatenation and substring matching.  This particular sort is especially slow, and doesn't seem to cache, even though this one field *is* indexed, so I wonder if there's anything I can do to speed up the sorting on this particular field (which is the default order by).

TYIA.

Comment: I think it's time to rebuild you table and database structure even if you say you can't do it. You can at least review all of the columns for the right column type.

Comment: @PeterKiss everywhere I was able to use a more optimal data type, I did, but as I mentioned a lot of these are "notes" type fields.  Anything more than what I've done is not gonna happen.  And without sorts, it runs fine - the bottleneck is all in the sort.

Comment: If i were you i would monitorize all the queryes in the background (aka save all query if it's possible) then i would run them with explain keyword and collect the most used columns and build sima indexes on them. Individual indexes on columns won't help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd have to index all 200 columns

That's not really a good idea. Because of the way MySQL uses indexes most of them would probably never be used while still generating quite a large overhead. (see chapter 7.3 in link below for details). What you could do however, is to try to identify which columns appear most often in `WHERE` clause, and index those.

In the long run however, you will probably need to find a way, to rework your data structure into something more manageable, because as it is now, it has the smell of 'spreadsheet turned into database' which is not a nice smell.

> I've read about sort_buffer_size but it seems like everything I read
>   conflicts with the last thing I read - is it advisable to increase
>   this value, or any of the other similar values (read_buffer_size,
>   etc)?

In general he answer is yes. However the actual details depend on your hardware, OS and what storage engine you use. See chapter 7.11 (especially 7.11.4 in link below)

> Also, the primary identifier is a crazy pattern they came up with in
>   the nineties.[...] I wonder if there's anything I can do to speed up
>   the sorting on this particular field (which is the default order by).

Perhaps you could add a `primarySortOrder` column to your table, into which you could store numeric values that would map the PK order (precaluclated from the store procedure you're using).

Ant the link you've been waiting for: [Chapter 7 from MySQL manual: Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html)

Comment: i like the primarySortOrder column idea. "spreadsheet turned db" - yep, actually an old FileMaker Pro db turned into MySQL db - but not much I can do about it. Records are filed with state and have to match exactly- fields that might be decimal can't be (e.g., some user put "$1,000,000 to $2,000,000" in an cost field - this kind of thing is the rule, not the exception).  One last q: if I'm not worried about searches (e.g. select a from t where a=1 order by a desc limit 25), but rather initial display (e.g. select a from t order by a desc limit 25), are there any strategies you'd suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to all the columns that have a large number of distinct values, say 100 or even 1000 or more. Tune this number as you go.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  virtually all columns will be distinct - most are free-text.  would you suggest indexing them all?

Comment: @BigMoMo Probably. The performance hit comes when you insert or update. Only you know the relative frequency of those w.r.t. reads and searches.